# Java xmpp tcp conection builder exception: "NoSuchFieldError: ifpossible"

Tags: java, xmpp

I'm trying to create an xmpp tcp connection by doing 
`Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();` but I'm getting the follwing error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ifpossible
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration$Builder.<init>(ConnectionConfiguration.java:505)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration$Builder.<init>(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.java:91)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration$Builder.<init>(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.java:87)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder(XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.java:80)
```

I've seen a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39347017/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-ifpossible). I'm not sure if it's problem with the class path. The jars seem to be included correctly. I'm using intellij. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like a version mismatch. Are you sure that all of your jars are the same version?
If you use Maven please add your dependencies to the question.